# Вывод ссылок PHPWord

Tags: ms-word, phpword

Есть в бд объемные тексты типа

```
<p>Параграф текста</p>
<p><a href="/">Это ссылка куда-то</a></p>
<p>Еще параграф текста</p>
```

Внутри текста встречаются ссылки.
По нажатию кнопки генерируется документ в phpword. 
Проблема в том, что ссылка отображается в документе просто как текст. Нужно что бы ссылка отображалась в документе гиперссылкой.
Есть идеи? Спасибо!

Comment: https://progi.pro/php-kak-sozdat-tekstoviy-fayl-soderzhashiy-giperssilki-3403336

Comment: Про $section->addLink(); я знаю. Проблема в том, что ссылки прячутся в тексте и нельзя разбить текст на части. Такой способ тут вряд ли подойдет. Это стандартный вывод ссылок в phpword. Возможно есть какой-то способ указывать ссылки в тексте в каком-то формате, который ворд документ интерпретирует как ссылку и правильно отобразит.